# including issue because of htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, php-7, include-path

This is my folder structure:

```
    - app 
      -- views
       --- assets
        ---- css files and stuff
       --- index.phtml (contains the homepage)
         ---- logged-in
           ----- dashboard.phtml
    - index.php (contains autoloading, including the router, etc)
    - .htaccess
```

This is in my htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The **problem** is: I want to include stuff from the assets folder in my dashboard.phtml. I've tried to include every possible path, but the problem is that my htaccess rewrites everything to my index.php and because of this, I keep having the same issues:

```
Warning: include_once(../components/footer.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Projects\projectname\app\views\logged-in\dashboard.phtml on line 158
```

How do I set my htaccess in a way that I don't have this problem anymore?

P.S. I had a hard time explaining this issue. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: `include_once '../components/menu.phtml';` for example

Comment: `include_once '../components/menu.phtml';` will be handled inside php and there is no Apache interaction

Comment: I don't see a components directory anywhere in the structure you posted.

Comment: No obviously not, but I do have one.. I didn't post the entire project structure.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: right before the line in question, do `print_r(scandir(__DIR__.'/../')); exit;` and see what is in this directory. If `components` is in that directory then do `print_r(scandir(__DIR__.'/../components/')); exit;` and see if `menu.phtml` is in that list.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you have a config file that you include on the top of the top level page that contains the root folder path as a constant. So `config.php`  would be in the domain root and include a constant (or a bunch of helpful constants): `define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);` Then when you include the config, you can include pages using the root path: `include(ROOT_DIR.'/app/components/footer.phtml');` I find it keeps everything consistent and easier to follow and change.